# Как реализовать на чистом CSS 3 адаптивные колонки

Tags: css3, html, css

Очень схематичный рисунок:

[image: img]

У средней колонки может быть разная ширина (но ширина не должна занимать больше 80% ширины экрана), а 1-я и 3-я колонка должны заполнять все свободное пространство как по горизонтали, так и по вертикали. Я мучился с разметкой, но сделать этого не смог. Очень базовая разметка со стилями лежит на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qVPW/2/). Буду благодарен за помощь.

HTML

```
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="center">2</div>
<div class="right">3</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    height:100px;
    width:20px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
.center {
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    height:100px;
    width:20px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: ну так и написать нужно все в процентах: http://jsfiddle.net/8qVPW/3/

Comment: А если ширина центрального контейнера не 80%? А, например 50%? Дело в том, чтоон может быть разной ширины. 80% - максимальна ширина.

Comment: размер центрального блока зависит от контента? Я правильно понимаю? Или как это получается, что ширина его может варьировать? Это не поддается управлению?

Comment: Да, центральный блок зависит от контента. И этим нельзя управлять (можно только указать максимальную ширину)

Comment: Как решить поставленную задачу одними силами стилей не знаю. Знаю как сделать плавающий средний блок в зависимости от размеров боковых, но такой вариант - еще не сталкивался! Нужно подумать, вдруг чего надумаю! Интересная задачка :)

Comment: Для меня уже сойдет решение и с js :)

Comment: Сами справитесь?

Comment: Вряд ли. Мои знания js близки к нулю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение. Лежит оно здесь - http://jsfiddle.net/T7M6f/. В решении мне помогла эта статья - http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/align-center/

Comment: Сделал Ваш комментарий ответом, подправьте.

Comment: Сделал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Грубое исполнение, но отсюда уже можно куда-то двигаться: [мышкой тырц](http://jsfiddle.net/8qVPW/7/)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я нашел средство сделать это на чистом CSS

Comment: Если подходит такое решение, то конечно. Проблема состоит в боковых блоках. Вы пробовали внести в них контент?

Comment: Я сейчас не за компьютером, но сейчас попробовал с айпэда внести контент. Вроде работает. 
Хотя конкретно в моей задаче в боковых колонках контента нет.

Comment: Да, это меняет дело. В вопросе Вы это не указали!

Comment: Извините. Бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант разметить блоки и дать левому и правому - **min-width:10%; max-width:30%** а центральному блоку задать **max-width:80% ; min-width:40%** . Мне кажется это будет логично и оптимально

Comment: Сделал, открыл, получил вот это http://prntscr.com/1ee795

Comment: И это не то, что Вы хотели сделать ?