# Адаптивная верстка на три блока

Tags: css, css3

Нужно такое сформировать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посередине блок, равный фиксированной ширине. Должен быть четко по центру страницы.
Слева и справа блоки, они растягиваются по всей оставшейся ширине страницы.

Как такое сделать, ***не применяя flex*** (сразу тяжелее стало, да?)?

Я додумался только сформировать два слоя: на первом будет центральный блок, он и будет позиционироваться по центру с помощью `margin: auto`.
А остальные два будут занимать `width: 50%`, но находится под ним и таким образом создаться ощущение адаптивности.
Но хотелось бы без костылей. Я о таком потом могу пожалеть просто... По той же причине нельзя использовать флексы.

Comment: не вспомню когда, но на toster был уже подобный вопрос и ответ...

Comment: @sagan, вот незадача, мне он нужен тут, в ответах желательно) На тостере ничерта никогда не находится. И сейчас не нашел. На [SO](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/235016/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-css-3-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) нашел решение, но оно с костылями. То есть там, о чем я и говорил, костыль используется: левый и правый блоки лежат под средним. Это неприемлемо.

Comment: а почему не сделать display: table и считать ширину через calc?

Comment: @KAGGDesign, честно говоря, не верстал таблицами никогда. Может быть, можно, не знаю, приложи решение, я посмотрю (:

Comment: flexbox нельзя, а grid можно?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, что такое grid? Что-то из бутстрап, что ли?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, [погуглил](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20grid). Никому нельзя пока использовать) Впервые услышал о таком свойстве если честно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 340px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% - 340px);
  width: calc(50% - 340px);
  background: yellow;
}

.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 680px;
  background: magenta;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: -webkit-calc(50% - 340px);
  width: -moz-calc(50% - 340px);
  width: calc(50% - 340px);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, вполне себе решение. Подходит. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавил кроссбраузерные префиксы для calc.

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, для чего вам нужны блоки слева и справа?

Comment: @Viktor не понял. В вопросе три блока заявлено.

Comment: Как я понял, основная задача отцентрировать центральный блок для любой ширины экрана, так? Можно же обойтись 1 блоком с margin: 0 auto и фиксированной шириной, правильно?

Comment: Я думаю, если бы ТС был нужен один блок, он бы так и спросил. Обычно верстку на 3 блока используют для симметричного размещения текста в центре и двух картинок по краям, выровненных по вертикали.

Answer (score 3):

Можно обычными флоатами и при помощи свойства `width: calc((100% - 500px) / 2)` для боковых элементов.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.side {
  width: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
  float: left;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.center {
  float: left;
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.center--nofloat {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="center center--nofloat"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class=container>
  <div class=side></div>
  <div class=center></div>
  <div class=side></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Наверно, можно было бы и ими... Просто флоаты не нравятся сами по себе, но с такой задачей справятся. Правда всё равно таблица в моей изначальной задаче более выгодна, планируется анимация и, кажется, с таблицей будет меньше мороки. Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, все таки флоаты лучше. Таблицы уже давно для таких целей использовать моветон, имхо..